# AngularJS "Controller Undefined error" while displaying the scope value in .php extension file

Tags: php, angularjs, angularjs-scope

while displaying the scope value in file with ".php" extension gives an error of undefined controller, while it displays the scope value properly.

Sample Code:

```
<script>
  (function(){
    var app = angular.module('demoApp', []);
    app.controller('DemoCtrl', function($scope){
      $scope.name = "test";
    });
  })();
</script>
<div ng-app="demoApp">
  <div ng-controller="DemoCtrl">
      {{name}}
  </div>
</div>
```

The above code, shows the value of name in browser correctly , but in console gives the following error

"angular.min.js:103 Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.11/ng/areq?p0=DemoCtrl&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined"

What is wrong with the code? The angular version used is **1.3.11**

Comment: Your current code looks fine. Is that the only code inside it?

Comment: @Aparna where are you printing in console?

Comment: Yes, its a sample code, Just to reflect the error I added the sample code. Any solution?

Comment: @Sajeetharan: I am not printing in console, While running the php page I am getting the error of controller undefined

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/sh4Lmce1/ Woks fine. This is not reproducible, unless you're hiding some other code somewhere else

Comment: @Aparna The code you showed here should not give any error!

Comment: @AlonEitan : Within the HTML page it runs fine, but the code is in ".php" extension, not in html. I never did controller binding with the php file before.

Comment: So you're just changing the extension to PHP and it stop working, you're you have some other PHP code inside (before or after the current code provided in the question)

Comment: @AlonEitan :  No This is the only code, no any extra code. I was unable to create the plnkr with php file. Thats why I wrote here the sample code

Comment: I think that in that case you should use HTMLs and JS files. You're developing SPA, so I don't see how uglifying the code with PHP will help you, its conflicting with the essence of single page applications (You use `$http` or `$resource` to get the data back from the server, while the client is a pure HTML and JS)

Comment: @AlonEitan :  Yes. Okay, You said is true.